# Creating a for Loop in bs4 for Ebay listings

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup, iterator

I have the following code that goes to an ebay url and extracts the name of a listing and sale price, see below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import request

html = urlopen('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=manga&_sacat=0&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

soldItem = soup.find('h3', class_='s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags')
salePrice = soup.find('span', class_='POSITIVE')

#data = soup.find('div', class_='s-item__info clearfix')

itemData = {soldItem.get_text():salePrice.get_text()}
```

I want to create a for loop that iterates over the first page and gives me the name and sale price of every listing.

However, every single attempt that I've made returns either the same listing five times or all sold items and thereafter all sale prices.

Any hints as to how to format my for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code that will create all items and their prices in a dictionary by the key of the item name and the value of the price.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = urlopen('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=manga&_sacat=0&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

soldItem = soup.find_all('h3', class_='s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags')
salePrice = soup.find_all('span', class_='POSITIVE')

itemsData = {item.text: price.text for item, price in zip(soldItem, salePrice)}

print(itemsData)
```

Comment: well that's one way to solve my problem, I still have a problem with creating the for loop. that being said can you go over your variable named itemsData, idk why that works

Comment: I'm not sure what is required can you provide a bit more details?

Comment: thanks for your help ! No worries, I was able to find the answer to this problem. I'll have to study your reply in more detail to see why it works. Thanks